# Provide different constructor arguments to a common dependency based on dependant class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I'm using Spring Boot and configure it with annotations. Say I have following classes:

```
@FunctionalInterface
@Component
public interface VerificationStrategy {
    void verify(Foo foo) throws Exception;
}

@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    public A(VerfificationStrategy assumption) {}
}

@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired
    public B(A a) {}
}

@Component
public class C {
    @Autowired
    public C(A a) {}
}
```

Now what I would like to achieve:

- Instance of B should receive instance of A with one implementation of `VerificationStrategy`
- Instance of C should receive instance of A with some other implementation of `VerificationStrategy`

What's the most elegant and efficient way to achieve that using annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with Spring. You would need to create two implementations of A class.

But you can do something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface VerificationStrategy {
    void verify(Foo foo) throws Exception;
}

@Configuration
public class VerificationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public VerificationStrategy strategy1() {
        return (foo) -> {System.out.println(foo);};
    }

    @Bean
    public VerificationStrategy strategy2() {
        return (foo) -> {System.out.println(foo);};
    }
}    

@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired
    public B(@Qualifier("strategy1") VerificationStrategy a) {}
}

@Component
public class C {
    @Autowired
    public C(@Qualifier("strategy2") VerificationStrategy a) {}
}
```

Comment: This satisfies my request for _elegant_ solution.